# How to display image in list in MVC?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, uiimageview

I'm a final year student, working on FYP, I have an issue about fetching image that is stored in binary data in database. I tried lots of solutions, I've searched on Google, but not working any solution.

View

```
@model IEnumerable<PictureServices.Picture>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 <tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <td>
            @{
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.image);
                var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
            }
            <img src='@imgsrc' style="max-width:100px; max-height:100px;">
        </td>
```

model

```
public class Picture
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public byte[] image { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }  
}
```

controller

```
 public class CarServicesController : Controller
{

    TestingEntities db = new TestingEntities();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Picture ds = new Picture();
        var item = (from d in db.Pictures
                    select d).ToList();

        return View(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the byte array to base 64 string and use that as the image source. You can use the `Convert.ToBase64String` to do so. One thing you must do is a **`null`** check before trying to convert the byte array as that could be null.

```
@model IEnumerable<PictureServices.Picture>    
<table class="table table-striped">
@foreach (var r in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@r.Id</td>
        <td>@r.Name</td>
        <td>
            @if (r.Image != null)
            {
               var imgSrc = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(r.Image)}";
               <img src="@imgSrc" alt="@r.Name" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I would also recommend using [PascalCasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for C# class properties ( `Name` instead of `name`).

Comment: I tried this one as you directed, but it did not work, debugging was stopped at breakpoint.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions  ?

Comment: Showing no any error, browser redirects back to Controller file after little searching. There is no any error showed in VS.

Comment: Only this line is appearing in Call Stack window

PictureServices.dll!PictureServices.Controllers.CarServicesController.Index() Line 16 C#

Comment: Inner exception should tell sometihing. Do you have valid byte array in those table columns ?

Comment: Yeah they are in proper form in binarydata stored in columns as I mentioned in question.

Comment: Are you getting  the view rendered ? Check the view source and see whether it generated the base64 string. I would also clean and rebuild the solution

Comment: It renders view in proper way and also showing other column values from table but not sowing only images from table.